# How can the following program from Khan Academy even work?

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
def factorial(number):
    product = 1

    for  i in range(number):

        product = product * (i + 1)

    return product

user_input = input("enter a non negative number:")

factorial_of_the_number = factorial(user_input)

print(factorial_of_user_input)
```

I have just started programming. Please state the simplest explanation. 
My question being, since the user input is assigned to the variable *user_input* and not the variable *number*.  how does *factorial* function recognizes the user input?

Also what does it mean by *return product* function??

Comment: You should read this section of the Python Tutorial about functions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: As a side note: It looks like this is Python 2 code (despite using a Python 3-style `print`), because otherwise `user_input` (and therefore `number`) is going to be a string, not a number. If you're just learning programming in 2018, unless you're specifically learning to work on legacy code, you really should learn a recent version, not an version from the last decade that's going to permanently go out of support in a year and a half.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `factorial(user_input)`, `user_input` is first evaluated to a value, and then that value is given to the `factorial` function.  The function binds all the values it receives to the appropriate names in the local symbol table (a mapping between identifiers and values), then begins execution.

The `factorial` function doesn't know that the value came from your `user_input` variable.

In fact, you can call functions using values without assigning them to names first.  `factorial(5)` and `factorial(randint(0, 10))` are also valid function calls.

Answer (score 2):

This program works because this snippet of code:

```
factorial(user_input)
```

Takes the value of the variable `user_input` and passes it to the `number` variable 
specified in the `def factorial(number):` function when the function is called.

This works as such because Python is a "Pass By Value" language. The input'ed variable is not used in the function, rather the value associated with it is passed into the function and assigned to a new variable.

**Extra Info:**
Java is an example of a "Pass by Reference" Language. I.E. it would use the original variable instead of passing it to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `user_input` variable gets passed to the `factorial()` function with this line

```
factorial_of_the_number = factorial(user_input)
```

Then the the math is handled inside the `factorial()` function and returned to be stored in the `factorial_of_the_number` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function factorial takes a number which has been passed it while calling this function. There is no such necessity that the variable name should be same.